# Склонение фамилий Махиня и Ковбаня

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, склоняется ли фамилия Махиня (муж.) и Ковбаня (жен.). Насколько я знаю по родословной, эти фамилии не склонялись ни у кого.

Answer (score 1):

Фамилии оканчивающиеся на безударные -а/-я всегда склоняются, независимо от того, мужчине или женщине принадлежат.
Редчайшими исключениями являются случаи появления при склонении не благозвучности или, еще реже, трудностей при восстановлении исходной формы.

В рассматриваемых фамилиях подобных особенностей не наблюдается. Поэтому общая рекомендация: склонять, по обычным правилам, подобно омонимичному имени нарицательному: Капуста, Капусты, Капусте и т. д.

Что касается постоянно встречающихся отсылок носителей к истории якобы несклоняемой (или имеющей особенности при склонении) фамилии, то это обычно не принимается во внимании при выработке рекомендаций (кроме отдельных случаев фамилий спорного происхождения). В нашем случае этот факт просто не является значимым, склонять надо.

И. кто? Махиня, Ковбаня
Р. кого? Махини, Ковбани
д. кому? Махине, Ковбане

и т. д.

Это в полной мере относится к фамилиям и мужчин, и женщин.